# Intermediate SSL Cert

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, node.js

I have an SSL certificate that is self-signed, and therefore uses an intermediate certificate.   I am using Node.js and returning both the certificate as well as the certificate chain which includes the intermediate certificate.

It appears that for some people, this works fine but for others it throws an invalid certificate error. Browser/version combination does not seem to matter.

Why would this happen? In what ways can I debug this to find the reason? I cannot seem to resolve it, or even know what ways I can find out what's wrong or why SSL is complaining.

Comment: One solution is not to use a self-signed certificate. The other is to install the self-signed certificate into the operating system's `Certificate Store`. Different browsers look at different locations. Firefox is one of the few browsers that DO NOT look at the host operating system's `Certificate Store`.  Chrome, IE, Opera all look at `Certificate Store` when ran on OS X, Linux, and Windows

Comment: @Ramhound, I think your comment is a valid answer.

Comment: "I have an SSL certificate that is self-signed, and therefore uses an intermediate certificate. " That does not make sense. A self-signed certificate does not use an intermediate certificate - rather, it does not use any other certificate at all. That's what "self-signed" means, after all.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is not to use a self-signed certificate. The other is to install the self-signed certificate into the operating system's `Certificate Store`. Different browsers look at different locations.

Firefox is one of the few browsers that DO NOT look at the host operating system's `Certificate Store`. Chrome, IE, Opera all look at `Certificate Store` when ran on OS X, Linux, and Windows