# SSL Cert only valid

Tags: ssl, squid, tls

Similar to [Intermediate SSL Cert](https://superuser.com/questions/656597/intermediate-ssl-cert)

I have a router that I'm running a squid cache on. The thing is, everything is https nowadays, so I've enabed MITM SSL filtering to cache https.

I'm fairly certain what this does is terminate SSL at the router instead of at my PC. I have a self-signed cert on the router for this. I've added that cert to the cert store on my PC, but it only works sometimes.

Going to https://www.facebook.com loads totally fine. However, going to, say https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html, or even the superuser login page gives me `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Also, bonus question. Does this mean that I use my PC's cert for SSL to the router, and the from there use the router's self signed cert, or is the data going from my PC to the router totally unencrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are most likely running into is "Public Key Pinning" - basically your browser has a record of some domain names recorded directly - and your MITM attack on the SSL (to proxy it) is failing, because the signer of the cert you are receiving via the SSL Intercepting Squid is different to what the cert believes it should be.

[This link](https://blog.digicert.com/firefox-32-supports-public-key-pinning/) will explain whats going on (and indeed is from the CA issuing the Facebook Cert)

In order to get round this you will need to disable pinning in your browser - how you do that will depend on your browser.

**For my bonus points :>**

Your computer is using a self-signed connection to your squid proxy.  Your squid proxy is using a real SSL connection to the outside world.  Everything is encrypted ( but not neccesarily by the correct party, hence the errors popping up)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this you need to either install the intermediate certificate or use different browser. As browsers are preinstalled with intermediate certificates, even you can try upgrading your browser